# YUI treeview not getting refreshed

Tags: treeview, yui, yui2

I am using **YUI treeview** to show some hierarchical structure.The problem is that even when I delete some nodes from back end and then refresh the whole tree it does not reflect the changes done on back end.(i.e If I remove a certain node from database and then refresh the page containing the tree view it still shows the deleted node in tree.)

Ironically this issue is just specific to IE 8 and 9.

I dont face this issue in chrome and firefox.

is there a  way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be TreeView but too aggressive caching by the browser. IE is known to do that.  With the debugger, look at what information was actually transferred from the server.  In the refresh, the browser might be actually reading the data from its own cache.   If so, the problem is not YUI's. After all, it works in other browsers.

Comment: are you aware of any work around for this?I mean for IE

Comment: Googling 'prevent ie from caching'  returns millions of results.  Take your pick.

Comment: I have tried this things already.                              <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"> Apart from this I have tried this as well. response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);      Still nothing stops IE from caching that page.Do you any better solution @user3129262?

Comment: Without looking at your code, I can only guess. There are two issues that usually break things in IE that work on other browsers.  One is too much caching, the other is trailing commas when listing arrays. Like [1, 2, 3, ].  That last comma after the 3 can cause fatal errors in IE.